# Laravel query multiple usage

Tags: php, laravel

How can I using same query and just change the `where` statement like this:

```
$query = Transaction::ofBranch($this->merchant_id)->where(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), Carbon::now()->subMonths($value)->format('m'));
$count = $query->count();
$total_paid = $query->where('status',1)->sum('amount');
$total_unpaid = $query->where('status',0)->sum('amount');
```

I got all result except `$total_unpaid`.

When I check, it appears the query has been replaced by `total_paid`. So the `$total_unpaid` has no results.

Is there any way I can make it work or any idea to make it more efficient and no repeating the base query?

Thanks

Comment: Try to clone a `$query` before fetching `$total_paid` and `$total_unpaid` (You'll get, for example, `$query` and `$query2`). Then use `$query` for  `$total_paid` and `$query2` for `$total_unpaid`. Here I presume that "cloning" is not "repeating".

Comment: well, why I can't think that way! :\. Thanks Gino! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = Transaction::ofBranch($this->merchant_id)->where(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), Carbon::now()->subMonths($value)->format('m'));
```

**Solution is to use clone, by which your original query will remain same and will not change, when you will extend this query.**

E.g

```
$clone = clone $query;
```

You can use this instead `$query`
Use this

```
$count = $clone ->count();
```

Not this:

```
$count = $query->count();
```

Others will be like

```
$total_paid = $clone->where('status',1)->sum('amount');

$total_unpaid = $clone->where('status',0)->sum('amount');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$query = Transaction::ofBranch($this->merchant_id)->where(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'), Carbon::now()->subMonths($value)->format('m'));
 $count = $query->count();
 $total_paid = $query->where('status',1)->sum('amount');
 $total_unpaid = $query->orWhere('status',0)->sum('amount');
```